# Install KDE neon in legacy mode

Tags: system-installation, kde, plasma5

I did my usb booteable with ROSA Image Writer for [KDE neon](https://neon.kde.org/), but when I am booting in my computer the only options is in UEFI mode:
[image]

Is any way of do my usb booteable for install KDE neon without UEFI mode?

I tried install KDE neon like this but I got a error at end, installing GRUB:
[image]

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I cannot comment so I'm writing this as an answer. Instead of Rosa image writer can you try to create the usb drive using dd?

```
dd if=path_to.iso of=/dev/sd? bs=4M
```

where `path_to.iso` is the path containing the KDE Neon iso and `/dev/sd?` the usb's stick device.

The `dd` command is available in any linux distro, but it seems that there is a version for windows as well (haven't tried this)

http://www.chrysocome.net/dd